# Using dplyr to change all infrequent strings to 'other'

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of strings in my data frame and I'm trying to replace all but the **n** most frequently occurring strings to "other".

Though my current approach *works*, it seems very convoluted since it involves creating a **tibble** and using `%in%` to create a boolean vector.

So my question is: Is there an easier way to accomplish this using **dplyr** and, if so, how would I wrap it in a function and apply it across multiple columns using `mutate_all`?

```
library(dplyr)

# setting up the data frame:
letter.df <- data_frame(val=sample(1:25, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                        let=rep(x = letters[1:5], length.out=100))
letter.df[1:3, 2] <- c('x','y','z')


# my current approach more or less:
top5letters <- letter.df %>% 
  count(let) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  top_n(n=5)

idx <- letter.df$let %in% top5letters$let
letter.df$let[!idx] <- 'other'
```

Comment: If you want to apply this to multiple columns, could you provide a small example and expected output? Putting together the results doesn't seem very obvious to me

Comment: I already wrote my answer, but is there any reason the data _must_ be strings, as opposed to factors?

Answer (score 5):

#### Use forcats

The `forcats` package, part of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/), has a function `fct_lump()`, that does (I think) exactly what you want.

```
require(forcats)
letter.df %>%
    mutate(let = fct_lump(let %>% as.factor, n=5))
```

Forcats is designed for factors, so for your example data I had to turn the `let` column into a factor rather than a character.  And if you really wanted it to say "other" instead of "Other", you can do `fct_lump(..., n=5, other_level='other')`.

#### Demonstration w/ `mutate_all()`

```
letter.df %>%
    mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
    mutate_all(~fct_lump(.x, n=5))
```

Since `fct_lump()` is already a function, it's easy to use with `mutate_all()`

#### If conversion to a factor is the bottleneck

If your data is too large and conversion to a factor is the bottleneck, I'd recommend your approach from the question, but manually specificy which factor levels you want to keep.  That would let you do the "truncation" and the conversion in one step.

```
letter.df %>%
    mutate(let = factor(let, levels=top5letters$let))
```

(The only complexity is if you have `NA` in your original data that you don't want to blur with `'other'`, because this last approach converts all non-provided levels to `NA`.)

Comment: I was trying to avoid converting the strings to factors initially. Basically, in a given column there could be, say, 2,000 unique strings but the 30 most frequently occurring strings cover over 70% of the observations so (as a starting point, at least) I want to keep strings in the top 30, lump all the others as "other" and *then* convert the entire column to a factor. I guess I thought that a couple 100k rows of data would be too unruly to consider working with factors from the start but it sounds like `fct_lump` is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to add some possibilities for if you do have lots of strings and for some reason conversion to a factor is limiting.

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it may involve `right_join()`.

```
letter.df %>% 
count(let) %>%
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
top_n(n=5) %>%
right_join(letter.df, by = "let") %>%
mutate(let = ifelse(is.na(n), "other", let))
```

Comment: Interesting... I hadn't considered any sort of **join**. I'm just surprised that there's not a more straightforward approach and/or function... Any thoughts about how to bottle this up as a function?

Comment: You could `require(dplyr)` in the function? I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?

```
letter.df%>%count(let)%>%
arrange(desc(n))%>%
  mutate(let = ifelse(row_number()<=5,'other',let))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting (`tidyr::nest`) might be useful here

```
library(tidyverse)
letter.df %>%
  nest(val) %>%
  mutate(size = map_int(data, ~nrow(.x))) %>%
  arrange(desc(size)) %>%
  mutate(let = ifelse(row_number() > 5, "other", let)) %>%
  unnest(data)

# A tibble: 100 x 3
   # let    size   val
   # <chr> <int> <int>
 # 1 d        20     4
 # 2 d        20     2
 # 3 d        20    19
 # 4 d        20     2
 # 5 d        20    21
 # 6 d        20     6
 # 7 d        20    17
 # 8 d        20    14
 # 9 d        20    14
# 10 d        20    13
# ... with 90 more rows
```